# Jquery Mobile Image under Header bar

Tags: jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I am trying to build a sample template that has image under the header bar. You can [check the image of disney's old design for this](http://www.jqmgallery.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/disneyworld-160.jpg).

This design has the image under the header and before the page menus. How to place image in this case?

How to add such images on the index page or in any page? I tried with the background image but the effect applies to whole page which is not what I want. I am trying to get the image under the header and before the menu content as shown in the sample image.